# Create a symbolic link on a networked drive

Tags: windows, symbolic-link, network-drive, ntfs-junction

I'm trying to create a symbolic link on a networked drive that's mounted at login when my PC connects to a VPN.

I'm getting the following error:

[image: Error message]

I've come across [this](https://superuser.com/questions/210824/creating-a-symbolic-link-to-mapped-network-drive-in-windows) thread but it wasn't of much help.

Any thoughts?

Thanks for any assistance in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong parameters.

```
/D      Creates a directory symbolic link.  Default is a file symbolic link.
/J      Creates a Directory Junction.
```

A `/D` should work. A `/J` doesn't as it's a integral entity within the FS and with a share you don't have direct FS access. It's even telling you that it needs a local volume for `/J`.

For more information check: [What is the difference between NTFS Junction Points and Symbolic Links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9042542/what-is-the-difference-between-ntfs-junction-points-and-symbolic-links)

Comment: Whoops, I thought that thread I linked to used the '/J' option! I misread, thanks for the correction.