# Shared Folder not accessible from Admin

Tags: windows-7, batch, administrator, shared-folders

I'm using a Win7 VM ith VMWare. I setup a shared folder to access some file of my host machine. Now I'm trying to access it through a batch script :

```
xcopy /y "Z:\Desktop\test\*" "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\test\"
```

It's working when I launch the script normally, but not when executing it as admin..

Of course the rest of the script needs admin rights, that's why I execute this script as an admin.

I know that it is probably easy to fix but I didn't find how and I'm fed up to go round in circles..

Thanks !

Comment: Use UNC paths. Otherwise enable linked connections: http://woshub.com/how-to-access-mapped-network-drives-from-the-elevated-apps/. It’s been like this since Vista.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Command Prompt in Administrator mode doesn't see mapped drives](https://superuser.com/questions/690287/command-prompt-in-administrator-mode-doesnt-see-mapped-drives)

Comment: also, if the user account you're on is not the one with admin privileges (i.e. UAC prompts you for your admin password), `%username%` will be something different (it's the username of the account running the script).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Elevated command line prompt can't access shared drives](https://superuser.com/questions/199387/elevated-command-line-prompt-cant-access-shared-drives)