# How to run a program as nt authority\system using the windows RUNAS command (or using built-in tools if runas won't work)

Tags: administrator, runas

How do I run a program as `nt authority/system` **without** using 3rd party app (such as `psexec`)?

I have tried `runas "/user:system@nt authority" <app>` and `runas "/user:nt authority\system" <app>` but they all say `unable to acquire user password`.

(At least if there is no way using `runas` is there a way without using 3rd party apps?)

Answer (score 7):

One way is a temporary scheduled task that runs as `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM`. You can do this by pasting the below into PowerShell.

Explanation: The script prompts you for a command and its arguments. If there are no arguments, press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to leave them empty. The script then creates a temporary scheduled task named `RunAs_LocalSystem_$(New-Guid)`, which is set to run as `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM`. Finally, the script runs the scheduled task, then deletes it.

```
param( `
  [Parameter(Mandatory)][string]$Command, `
  [Parameter(Mandatory)][AllowEmptyString()][string]$Arguments `
) `
Import-Module ScheduledTasks; `
$name = "RunAs_LocalSystem_$(New-Guid)"; `
$actionArguments = @{ '-Execute' = $Command; }; `
if (-not [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($Arguments)) { $actionArguments['-Argument'] = $Arguments } `
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction @actionArguments; `
$principal = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserId 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM' -LogonType Interactive; `
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName $name -Action $action -Principal $principal | Start-ScheduledTask; `
Unregister-ScheduledTask $name -Confirm:$false
```

Comment: This is the correct and best answer. There is no need to use psexec or dll injection. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178437/start-remote-process-within-the-context/8818377#8818377

Answer (score 1):

You can't using `runas` probably because of the below:

"The LocalSystem account is a predefined local account used by the service control manager. This account is not recognized by the security subsystem, so you cannot specify its name in a call to the **LookupAccountName** function. It has extensive privileges on the local computer, and acts as the computer on the network. Its token includes the NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM and BUILTIN\Administrators SIDs; these accounts have access to most system objects. The name of the account in all locales is .\LocalSystem. The name, LocalSystem or ComputerName\LocalSystem can also be used. This account does not have a password."

[Reference](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b3cde003-6109-434e-85a1-9924bdfd5f3a/nt-authoritysystem-password?forum=sqlsecurity).

PSExec basically uploads and starts a Windows service PSEXECSVC through SMB.  It's possible for a Windows service installed with admin privileges (provided by PSExec command line) to run as the LocalSystem account (that's specifiable in `services.msc`, for example).  When you are "remoted in" to a system via PSExec you are actually talking to the running PSEXECSVC temporarily installed on the other end over the SMB protocol.  I'm not sure on further finer details but this is likely how PSExec is able to do things as the LocalSystem account.

[Reference](https://www.contextis.com/en/blog/lateral-movement-a-deep-look-into-psexec).

So you *might* be able to run it as LocalSystem by wrapping the executable in a service wrapper such as `srvany.exe` from the Windows 2000 Resource Kit (if it still works) or [NSSM](https://nssm.cc/) but if the executable tries to use Windows UI elements it will probably not work (that was disabled after Windows XP).

[Also read this](https://superuser.com/questions/1067246/is-nt-authority-system-a-user-or-a-group?noredirect=1&lq=1).